# Que tan objetiva debe ser mi respuesta al momento de contestar cualquier pregunta?

Tags: discusión, soporte

He visto como usuarios colocan respuesta de código solamente sin explicar y la califican como correcta, sin el usuario documentar nada! es correcto esto?

Comment: Quizás podrías explicar un poco más lo que preguntas. El cuerpo de tu pregunta y su título me parecen dispares. Que una respuesta sea objetiva me parece una cuestión distinta a que tenga solo código.

Comment: Aunque respuestas con código solamente son técnicamente válidas, en general se consideran de baja calidad y de poca utilidad. A menudo notarás que algunos usuarios dejan comentarios debajo de estas respuestas para animar al que contesta a mejorar la calidad de la respuesta. En algunos casos, hasta puede que algunos decidan darle un voto negativo.

Comment: Muy Buen comentario Sr. sstan

Comment: Daniel: Bienvenido. Como menciona Jose Antonio, la pregunta no es clara. Revisa [ask].

Comment: Pero la objetividad no tiene que ver con el código, sino con opiniones basadas en hechos comprobables. Entonces estás hablando de dos cosas distintas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bueno, si el codigo es entendible para el usuario y responde plenamente a su interrogante es valido. La idea es ayudar al usuario a llegar a la respuesta que está buscando, sin embargo, siempre es bueno explicar el codigo que compartes, asi otros usuarios que lleguen al post por el mismo problema tambien puedan entender el por qué de tu respuesta.

Comment: Bienvenido Luis. Tenemos lineamientos para las respuestas los encuentras en [answer].

Comment: Has dado en el clavo Luis. En efecto, lo importante es que la respuesta sea entendible y responda plenamente a su interrogante. Es decir, que sea útil. La forma en que se haga es secundaria. Excelente respuesta.